# What is a good etymological dictionary for the Persian language?

Tags: etymology, resource-request, persian

There are dozens of etymological dictionaries for Persian, has somebody compared them, and if yes could you recommend me a good one?

Answer (score 3):

Johnny Cheung: Etymological dictionary of the Iranian verb. You need to look up the New Persian words in the index, which will then refer you to the appropriate entry in the main section.

Paul Horn: Neupersische Etymologie, is old, but still usable.

Everything else is worthless.

Comment: Horn can be found here: https://archive.org/details/grundrissderneu00horngoog/page/n8

Comment: Thank you so much, have any other resource to recommend in english ?